# Gunicorn sock file not generated

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have an django application which I want to run using gunicorn and nginx. I have my application installed in this directory:

```
/website/davidbien/
```

I get to the point where I run django's dev webserver and can access that. I then run:

```
gunicorn davidbien.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And this works fine as well. After this I create a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="davidbien"                                  
DJANGODIR=/website/davidbien             
SOCKFILE=/website/virtual/run/gunicorn.sock  
USER=ec2-user                                        
GROUP=ec2-user                                    
NUM_WORKERS=3                                     
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=davidbien.settings             
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=davidbien.wsgi                     

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

cd $DJANGODIR
source ../virtual/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
--name $NAME \
--workers $NUM_WORKERS \
--user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
--bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
--log-level=debug \
--log-file=
```

And this runs fine as well as I get:

```
Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
Arbiter booted
Listening at: unix:/website/virtual/run/gunicorn.sock (3354)
[INFO] Using worker: sync
[INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3361
[INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3362
[INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3363

[DEBUG] 3 workers
```

The problem is that .sock file is not generated at all! I can't move on with nginx config as this file is not available. I gave 777 access to /website/ folder and everything inside it but this still doesn't work. I tried sudo as well and nothing. Logs show that it's working so how come it doesn't work? Thanks.

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: I changed OS to ubuntu. This example was on amazon's OS.